# Dynamic List Value Changed Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, render, directive

**Dynamically Compiled Html With Nested Directives**

I have some code that dynamically generates some html containing angular directives. Since the directives are late-bound I need to get them to be executed and generate their respective template contents. In the following example the detail row contains the html that has been dynamically generated. Within that generated row there is a custom directive () that needs to be rendered.

**Some Code to Compile the Nested Directive**

```
var detailRow = e.detailRow; // This is the html I want to compile. 

angular.element(document).injector().invoke(function ($compile) {
  // Get the scope from the html
  var scope = angular.element(detailRow).scope();
  // Compile using the scope. 
  $compile(detailRow)(scope);
});

// Get some data from custom directive. 
var testId = detailRow.find("random-testees").attr("testid");
```

**Attempt to Manage Supposedly-Newly-Compiled-Nested Directive**

The following snippet gives me limited success. With the timeout it seems that the directive is rendered as expected--catch is that it only works if I refresh the page. When I say rendered, I mean that the directive has been filled out with the template content.

```
// Wait, and call method on the directive. 
setTimeout(function () {
   var randomTesteesScope = $("random-testees").first().children(":first").scope();
   randomTesteesScope.loadTestees(this);
}.bind(testId),200);
```

**Empty Directive**

Before the screen refresh there is always an error in that the first child in the previous code is undefined. This indicates that the directive hasn't rendered yet. In fact, when I use a jQuery to peek at the directive element I can confirm it is empty ( NOTE there are no children in the directive).

**The Hack Doesn't Really Work**

You can see my attempt to hack (200ms setTimeout) the code giving a timeout so that the content has time to do whatever it has to do to complete its compile. But, as stated I need a screen refresh for any results.

**Need Deterministic Way to Call the loadEmployees Scope Function**

Really what I need is a deterministic way to call code on the directive once the directive has finished rendering.

**Wrong Assumption**

If my assumption is wrong about the compilation taking time, how do I render the directive in a deterministic way so I can execute the code after it has been rendered.

Answer (score 0):

This is what `scope.$apply` is for. Specifically `scope.$evalAsync` (another scope method which calls a digest) which places the function given to it in a queue to be executed after the current digest so that you don't get a `digest in progress` error.

Try:

```
randomTesteesScope.$evalAsync(function(){randomTesteesScope.loadTestees(this)});
```

references:

[docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope)

[Helpful article on scopes](http://teropa.info/blog/2013/11/03/make-your-own-angular-part-1-scopes-and-digest.html)